# Database table join displays multiple entries of same rows when I only want one

Tags: mysql, join

I am doing a table join on a mysql databse.

I want the results to display just once but it displays each time there is an entry matching the query.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$descquery = "SELECT streams.name, streams.desc, users.streamnumber FROM streams, users WHERE users.streamnumber = '$_POST[streamnumber]' AND users.streamnumber = streams.name";

$result = mysql_query($descquery) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out the contents of each row into a table 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['desc'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

This prints out multiple entries of what I want. Just wondered if theres something im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the **DISTINCT** clause, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT streams.name, streams.desc, users.streamnumber FROM streams, users WHERE users.streamnumber = '$_POST[streamnumber]' AND users.streamnumber = streams.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name, s.desc, u.streamnumber 
FROM streams s INNER JOIN users u
    ON u.streamnumber = '$_POST[streamnumber]'
   AND u.streamnumber = s.name
```

Remember you MUST always sanitize user input before using it in a query to avoid sql-injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ive just added the DISTINCT as @Marius suggested.

Comment: @JamesG: it's exactly what I suggested in my answer, posted long time before Marius's. Note that it could be really better using `JOIN` syntax to join tables than using `WHERE` to do it, because it's powerful and flexible. In this case engine convert it to same execution plan, but don't use it as a rule. Use `JOIN`, it was born for this reason!